# Does the word "agree" have more than one meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Suppose the word agree just has the meaning of agreeing with an opinion and to say you agree with that opinion means you have that opinion. Furthermore, suppose that every time somebody says they agree to something, they truthfully mean they have that opinion. Finally, suppose people don't feel forced to have a certain opinion. I will show that a contradiction can be derived from those assumptions and then suggest an alternate way to define things.

Sometimes people sign a form saying they agree to something. Using the first two of the 3 assumptions, we can deduce that they actually have the opinion that what the form is saying is the best way to do things. On the other hand, we know that people have many different opinions so using the third assumption, we can derive that they don't really agree with what they signed that they agree with. Now we can derive the contradiction that they both agree and don't agree with the form.

I know some people say English is flexible. That's probably because they have the opinion that there's nothing wrong with sometimes saying something that isn't literally true to convey a message that's not what the sentence literally means. For example, we could use the word "agree" with another meaning. For example, we could decide that when we sign a form saying we agree, we really mean we promise that we will do what the form said and that doesn't necessarily mean we really have the opinion that what it said is the best way to do things.

Doug Ford is the premier of Ontario and John Tory is the mayor of the capital city of Ontario, Toronto. I once learned, probably by reading the internet, that Mayor Tory and Premier Ford agreed to accept their differences and work together to solve the housing crisis. I suspect they literally said they agreed to accept their differences. If so, could it by that when they said they said they agreed accept their differences, they were using the second meaning of the word "agree" when they actually used the word "agree" in that sentence but were using the first meaning of the word "agree" when they said they accepted their differences. That is, accepting their differences can be thought of as meaning disagreeing with each other using the first meaning of the word "agree". If that is the case, then maybe each of them was disagreeing with the other about some stuff but was like "If I do it a certain way that I agree is better using the first meaning of the word 'agree', the other will destroy my work so there's no point in doing it that way so I promised that I would do it a different way because it's better to do it that way in my opinion because if I do it that way, the other won't destroy my work."

What do you think? I know there is more than one way to define things that some people would have the opinion to define that way. Would it be possible for you to tell me what you think would be different opinions on how people would choose to define things in different contexts?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. The word *agree* clearly has more than one meaning (check any dictionary). Are you asking us to pretend that it doesn't have more than one meaning and to check the logic following that supposition? Or are you asking how we decided which of a word's multiple meaning applies in a given context?  Neither of those are very good fits for this site, unfortunately.

Comment: The issue isn’t with the definition of *agree* - it is with the subject of the purported agreements.

Comment: I didn't think of checking the dictionary. I don't have an oxford dictionary but I suppose that if I plan to ask another question like this one, I will buy one before asking it. I didn't realize the research that was used to form multiple meanings for the dictionary had already been done. I feel that sometimes, I can't be sure that a certain type of research has already been done.

Comment: Are you referring to the phrase "[agree to disagree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agree_to_disagree)"?

Comment: @JayElston I can't tell you sure what you mean by what you're asking. You weren't clear. I'm guessing you're asking me whether I thought Mayor Tory and Premier Ford if they said "agree to disagree" would have used two meanings of the word agree in the phrase "agree to disagree" or an equivalent question. If that's what you were asking, then the answer is yes. The real question I had was not that question but an equivalent question of whether we could define it to have multiple meanings and what other people think of it. I just gave the example of Mayor Tory and Premier Ford as an example and

Comment: not as a question. The real question was multiple questions in the last paragraph. I suppose the first 3 paragraphs alone could be interpreted as a stand alone question with the fourth being an example given after the question.

Comment: You don't need to buy an Oxford dictionary specifically, there are a number of free online dictionaries that will provide the information you need for this sort of question. Dictionary.com lists [ten meanings for agree](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/agree).

Comment: 'we can deduce that they actually have the opinion that what the form is saying is the best way to do things'. No we can't, we can only know that it is the way they have agreed to adopt.

Comment: Your basic premises seem to be flawed -- we can hardly assume that people are always truthful. With false premises you can easily derive contradictions.

Comment: I don't understand this part of your agument: **people have many different opinions so using the third assumption, we can derive that they don't really agree with what they signed that they agree with** If I sign that the sky is blue, and I also have the opinion that grass is green and the ocean is wet, how do those imply that I don't really agree that the sky is blue?

Comment: It's not my fault that you can't figure out what I mean. I believe I made the argument as clear as I'm currently able to in the question. If you still can't understand it, I probably have no way to explain it to you in a way that you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully, for the word AGREE the Merriam Webster website offers some seven definitions, several of those having multiple sub-definitions. I hope you'll AGREE to read thoroughly, the contents of the following link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agree